# Нужен ли дефис в этом предложении?

Tags: орфография, приложение, дефис

Ставится ли дефис в этом предложении?

> У неё много подруг(-)кабардинок.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При отсутствии именных существительных(Дон, Москва, Сергей ...) в паре одиночных определяемого слова и приложения всегда ставится дефис, за исключением трех пунктов:

1. Приложение заменяется прилагательным: малютка сын = маленький сын ...
2. Род-вид отношения между приложением и определяемым словом: гриб лисичка, цветок мальва ...
3. Когда есть три слова-исключения: господин, товарищ, гражданин.
   Исходя из данной формализации, которой я руководствуюсь, в вашем предложении ставится дефис.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123385/discussion-on-answer-by-jim-korbett------).